# Connection aborted requests error

Tags: python, autologin

So this error occurs at 1.5 loop, it makes one full loop and stops at second function:

[image]

Target site freezes for some time and I see this:

[image]

Whats the problem?

Code:

```
import requests

def vissok(id):
    with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'http://www.worldofdraft.com/ajax/user.php'
    gameurl = 'http://www.worldofdraft.com/ajax/entry.php'
    GPL = ['5332', '5594', '5444', '5488', '5547', '5371', '5383', '5061', '5456', '5451', '5550']
    BPL = ['5388', '5596', '5481', '5587', '5585', '5514', '5099', '5249', '5566', '5501', '5357']
    GID = id
    UDID = '0'
    ACT = 'draft'
    ACT2 = 'save_draft'
    SIGN = '18852c5f48a94bf3ee58057ff5c016af'
    USERNAME1 = 'email@randommail.com'
    USERNAME2 = 'email2@randommail.com'
    PASSWORD = 'supersecretpass'
    LOGIN = 'login'
    c.get(url)
    login_data = dict(action = LOGIN, login = USERNAME1, password = PASSWORD)
    c.post(url, data = login_data)

    c.get(gameurl)
    game_data = dict(player_id = GPL[0], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = GPL[1], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = GPL[2], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = GPL[3], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = GPL[4], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = GPL[5], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = GPL[6], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = GPL[7], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = GPL[8], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = GPL[9], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = GPL[10], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data_save = dict( action = ACT2, id = GID, user_draft_id = UDID, sign = SIGN)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data_save)


def simplebot(id):  
with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'http://www.worldofdraft.com/ajax/user.php'
    gameurl = 'http://www.worldofdraft.com/ajax/entry.php'
    GPL = ['5332', '5594', '5444', '5488', '5547', '5371', '5383', '5061', '5456', '5451', '5550']
    BPL = ['5388', '5596', '5481', '5587', '5585', '5514', '5099', '5249', '5566', '5501', '5357']
    GID = id
    UDID = '0'
    ACT = 'draft'
    ACT2 = 'save_draft'
    SIGN = '18852c5f48a94bf3ee58057ff5c016af'
    USERNAME1 = 'email@randommail.com'
    USERNAME2 = 'email2@randommail.com'
    PASSWORD = 'supersecretpass'
    LOGIN = 'login'
    c.get(url)
    login_data = dict(action = LOGIN, login = USERNAME2, password = PASSWORD)
    c.post(url, data = login_data)

    c.get(gameurl)
    game_data = dict(player_id = BPL[0], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = BPL[1], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = BPL[2], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = BPL[3], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = BPL[4], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = BPL[5], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = BPL[6], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = BPL[7], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = BPL[8], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = BPL[9], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data = dict(player_id = BPL[10], action = ACT, id = GID)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
    game_data_save = dict( action = ACT2, id = GID, user_draft_id = UDID, sign = SIGN)
    c.post(gameurl, data = game_data_save)


i = 184
while i < 189:
    simplebot(i)
    vissok(i)
    i += 1
```

Comment: You need to throttle your requests. Basic bot writing, you can't Hammer the site like you do

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to throttle concept!

Comment: Normally you let someone else give you the answer to your question here on Stack Overflow so people get the points they deserve. It's one of the things that drive people to give answers in the first place. Comments are more a section to figure out what the root cause is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you need to throttle your request.
You've managed to solve this issue on your own and it should work.

I would propose a more cleaner and salable solution where you create a `GET` and `POST` function that keeps track of the last time you made a request and also makes for less code.

Have a look at:

```
import requests
from time import time, sleep

url = 'http://www.worldofdraft.com/ajax/user.php'
gameurl = 'http://www.worldofdraft.com/ajax/entry.php'
GPL = ['5332', '5594', '5444', '5488', '5547', '5371', '5383', '5061', '5456', '5451', '5550']
BPL = ['5388', '5596', '5481', '5587', '5585', '5514', '5099', '5249', '5566', '5501', '5357']
GID = id
UDID = '0'
ACT = 'draft'
ACT2 = 'save_draft'
SIGN = '18852c5f48a94bf3ee58057ff5c016af'
USERNAME1 = 'email@randommail.com'
USERNAME2 = 'email2@randommail.com'
PASSWORD = 'supersecretpass'
LOGIN = 'login'

last_request = time()
def get(c, url):
    global last_request
    if time()-last_request < 2:
        sleep(2-(time()-last_request))
    ret = c.get(url)
    last_request = time()
    return ret

def post(c, url, data):
    global last_request
    if time()-last_request < 2:
        sleep(2-(time()-last_request))
    ret = c.post(url, data = login_data)
    last_request = time()
    return ret

def vissok(id):
    global url, gameurl, GPL, GID, UDID, ACT, ACT2, SIGN, USERNAME1, PASSWORD, LOGIN
    with requests.Session() as c:
        get(c, url)
        login_data = dict(action = LOGIN, login = USERNAME1, password = PASSWORD)
        post(c, url, data = login_data)

        get(c, gameurl)
        for index in range(0, len(GPL)-1):
            game_data = dict(player_id = GPL[index], action = ACT, id = GID)
            post(c, gameurl, data = game_data)

        game_data_save = dict( action = ACT2, id = GID, user_draft_id = UDID, sign = SIGN)
        post(c, gameurl, data = game_data_save)


def simplebot(id): 
    global url, gameurl, BPL, GID, UDID, ACT, ACT2, SIGN, USERNAME2, PASSWORD, LOGIN
    with requests.Session() as c:

        get(c, url)
        login_data = dict(action = LOGIN, login = USERNAME2, password = PASSWORD)
        post(c, url, data = login_data)

        get(c, gameurl)
        for index in range(0, len(BPL)-1):
            game_data = dict(player_id = BPL[index], action = ACT, id = GID)
            post(c, gameurl, data = game_data)

        game_data_save = dict( action = ACT2, id = GID, user_draft_id = UDID, sign = SIGN)
        post(c, gameurl, data = game_data_save)

i = 184
while i < 189:
    simplebot(i)
    vissok(i)
    i += 1
    sleep(30) # Not sure why you want to wait 30 seconds here, but i kept it.
```

Basically what I've done is I took all your variables and put them in the top of your code and made them global (since you used the exact same variables twice, this saves up a lot of space in your code reusing them instead of copying them).

Then I removed all individual `c.post` calls you had made that looked like this:

```
game_data = dict(player_id = BPL[0], action = ACT, id = GID)
c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
game_data = dict(player_id = BPL[1], action = ACT, id = GID)
c.post(gameurl, data = game_data)
```

And made a loop out of it, since the only thing that changed were `0` -> `1` -> `2` etc etc.

I also created a `get()` and `post()` function that basically does what you just did, but added a `sleep()` that counts the difference between 2 seconds and the time past since the last request, so it will wait "dynamically" up to 2 seconds between each GET and POST request.

Haven't verified this code, but hope it gives you an idea of what you could do with programming in the future.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for leading me to solution. I will update my project code as suggested by you. Thanks again for input!

Answer (score 0):

So site blocks me for sending too many requests. So some throttling must be done, so I put a time delay in my loop for 30 seconds and 2 seconds after each 'c.post'

```
import time

game_data2 = dict(player_id = BPL[0], action = ACT, id = GID)
c.post(gameurl2, data = game_data2)
time.sleep(2)
```

And loop looks like:

```
i = 193
while i < 2000:
    vissok(i)
    simplebot(i)
    print "id: %d done" % i
    time.sleep(30)
    i += 1
```